# Do pretrained tensorflow models need to be used by machines with the same versions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, raspberry-pi

I trained a cnn on a Linux machine with keras/tensorflow but can’t get the pretrained model to run on my Raspberry Pi. The model was made on Ubuntu 16.04 with Python 3.6.7, tensorflow version 1.7.0, CuDNN 7.0.5 and CUDA 9. I am trying to run it on the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ with Python 3.5.3 and tensorflow version 1.13.1.

I have no problem loading and running the pretrained model on the same machine it was created on. The issue is only when I try to run that same pretrained model on the RPi system. I end up getting a segmentation fault.

I tried updating the Linux machine that created the model to tensorflow 1.12 but after tensorflow 1.12 successfully installed, I got "Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize" errors, so I'd rather not go down that route. I want to know if it's possible to just use this pretrained model with tensorflow 1.13.1 on the RPi.

Here's what I'm doing on the RPi:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf

/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py:222: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.4 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.5
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py:222: RuntimeWarning: builtins.type size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 432, got 412

>>> print(tf.__version__)
1.13.1

>>> from keras.models import load_model
Using TensorFlow backend.

>>> model = load_model(save_dir+model_name)
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:263: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:3445: calling dropout (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) with keep_prob is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use `rate` instead of `keep_prob`. Rate should be set to `rate = 1 - keep_prob`.
2019-03-25 17:08:11.471364: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:124] Allocation of 209715200 exceeds 10% of system memory.
2019-03-25 17:12:55.123877: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:124] Allocation of 209715200 exceeds 10% of system memory.
Backend terminated (returncode: -11)
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault
```

I need some guidance on whether this is happening - are the versions incompatible? Maybe the model is too large for RPi (doubt it - it's a fairly shallow model with 18 layers)? The other forum posts I've seen with segmentation faults seemed a lot more dire (e.g., they can't even write standard commands in the Terminal without seeing a segmentation error) - this segmentation fault only happens (and happens repeatably) through the above commanding.

Any advice/help greatly appreciated!